# Fuzzy search between two lists?

Tags: python, nlp, token, fuzzy-search

Imagine that I have a list of tokens:

```
tokens_to_search = [
  'fox.com',
  'australia',
  'messi',
  'ronaldo',
  'British premier league'
]
```

And I have a sentence, which may include some words, relevant to the `tokens_to_search` content:

```
sentence = 'Messi scored a goal in the premier league, watch on the Fox News'
```

The sentence can be split into tokens:

```
tokens_from_sentence = [
  'messi',
  ...,
  'premier',
  'league',
  ...,
  'fox',
  'news'
]
```

How can I detect the words from the `tokens_to_search` into the `tokens_from_sentence` with some fuzzy search? So the result will be

```
[
  'fox.com',
  'messi',
  'British premier league'
]
```

The simple approach is to do a nested loop by calculating some token distance, but it's `O(N*M)`. Maybe there's a smart way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it have to be a fuzzy search? or you are just trying to improve performance?

Comment: @AnuragWagh yeah, it has to be.

Comment: Look into [that question with my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58791875/140837). It requires to index `tokens_to_search` which take some time, but might payoff in the long run since queries are very fast (100 times faster than fuzzywuzzy with better results). Also look into https://stackoverflow.com/q/52046394/140837 to learn how to link words or group of words into a Knowledge Base.